# Best way to ensure latest F# FAKE?

Tags: f#-fake

What is the best way to ensure that all developers and the build server are using the latest version of FAKE?

If a build.cmd like [the one from FSharp.Data](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/master/build.cmd) is used, the developer will not be on the latest until they delete FAKE from the packages folder or just delete the whole packages folder.

If you add FAKE as a dependency in .nuget\packages.config, your build.fsx script must include the version information and be updated each time you change versions. You will not automatically get the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With NuGet 2.8.1 you can remove the "if not exists" parts - NuGet will check (very slowly) if the latest FAKE is installed.